# Qual è il senso di "blandire" in questo passaggio?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Diamante rabbrividisce. Gli sta chiedendo di rubare. A un morto. I morti ammazzati sono i piú pericolosi e vendicativi fra i morti. Le preghiere non li **blandiscono**. Mai e poi mai.

Ho cercato il verbo "blandire" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a coglierne il senso nel brano sopra citato. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il significato di [blandire](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/blandire/) che si adatta al contesto da te citato è il seguente:

> Lusingare, allettare con parole carezzevoli: *b. gli animi*; contento
>   di *b. il marchese* ... per staccarlo un poco dal partito clericale
>   (Fogazzaro); *b. le passioni*, favorirle, secondarle. Anche, trattare
>   con modi blandi, rivolgere buone parole: soccorre i piccoli infermi,
>   li conforta, li blandisce (D’Annunzio)

Le preghiere non lusingano i morti ammazzati, non si fanno intenerire specie nei confronti di chi li deruba.

Comment: Ho l'impressione che *blandire* venga spesso usato nel senso di *intenerire*.

Comment: Guardando su Sabatini Coletti si trova anche il significato placare, lenire, mitigare